# How does the TrackButton property work on the TPopupMenu component?

Tags: delphi, toolbar, vcl, popupmenu, delphi-12-athens

I don't understand how the [`TrackButton` property](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Athens/en/Vcl.Menus.TPopupMenu.TrackButton) works.

> Specifies which mouse button activates the popup menu when it is associated with a toolbar button.
> Use TrackButton to specify which mouse button activates the popup menu when it is associated with a toolbar button.

So firstly. It only works on a `TToolButton` and nothing else?

I have a `TToolButton` with my popup assigned to it via the `PopUpMenu` property on the `TToolButton`, but it doesn't seem to work. I set the `TrackButton` to `tbLeftButton`, but it still opens with right click?

Or what am I not understanding? Can someone explain how it works please?

Comment: The documentation for `TPopupMenu.TrackButton` is blatantly wrong. The property has nothing to do with ToolButtons at all. In fact, the only place that `TToolBar`/`TToolButton` even uses the property is when activating a `TToolButton` whose `DropdownMenu` is nil and `MenuItem` is not nil. In that case, an internal `TPopupMenu` is created with `TrackButton = tbLeftButton` to display the `MenuItem`.  But the functionality of `TrackButton` is entirely inside of `TPopupMenu.Popup()` only, and so applies to any component that uses `TPopupMenu`.

Answer (score 4):

This has nothing to do with `TToolBar` and also not with any potential button on it.

As of Delphi 5 `TPopupMenu.TrackButton` is only used in `TPopupMenu.Popup()`, where its value (of either `tbRightButton` or `tbLeftButton`) is mapped to WinAPI's `TPM_RIGHTBUTTON` and `TPM_LEFTBUTTON` to be used (among others) as flags in the call to [`TrackPopupMenu()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-trackpopupmenu). There those constants have the following meaning:

> | constant | value | description |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | TPM_LEFTBUTTON | 0 | The user can select menu items **with only** the left mouse button. |
> | TPM_RIGHTBUTTON | 2 | The user can select menu items with **both** the left **and right** mouse buttons. |

Which means:

- `.TrackButton` applies to any popup menu anywhere, and
- it enables/disables to click on menu items **also** with the right mouse button (while the left mouse button is always available).

Comment: I'm still a little bit confused, but this helps a lot. Thanks. I will need to go play with it again after reading this.

Comment: @MartinKakhuis Create a `TPopupMenu`, add `TMenuItem`s, run your program and you can also click on those menu items with the right mouse button. Change the `.TrackMenu` property from `tbRightButton` to `tbLeftButton`, run your program and you can **only** click on the menu items with the left mouse button - the right click does nothing now.